# Facebook new page's layout and changing order of apps

Tags: facebook

I'm having several page's with the new layout.
I have several "Apps" (page tabs) in them

in the past you could change the order so you can see the first ones you want.

now there is only 3 and i can't find the way to change it's order

did anyone find this solution? Facebook's documentation has only the old design instructions

please try to share if you found the solution

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. Found the setting under "More -> Manage Tabs"